# Integrate LinkedIn sign-in in android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am trying to integrate LinkedIn Sign in in my app. But I am unable to find the proper  steps for it anywhere. Can someone please tell me the proper steps for doing that ? Can I do it without using any backend API?
Also, I want this done using a custom button rather than the login button provided by linkedin.

Answer (score 1):

Linkedin android-SDK is supported anymore. **In order to integrate the Linkedin sign-in android app, you need to use Linkedin auth APIs with Webview in android**.
 please check the developer note:  https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates

Follow LinkedIn official documentation for integration:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authentication.

Check this example:
https://github.com/mario595/android-oauth-linkedin-example

or this one,

https://johncodeos.com/how-to-add-sign-in-with-linkedin-button-to-your-android-app-using-kotlin/

Comment: What should be the redirect URL here ?

Comment: Redirect URLs  `https://YOUR_DOMAIN/login/callback`                                       Please take a look to the link for proper explanation    https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/linkedin

Comment: @Sneha Did it help ?.

Comment: You can find some more tutorials but in android `webview` is the way to integrate LinkedIn sign in. I can help more if you let me know where you are stuck right now.

Comment: https://johncodeos.com/how-to-add-sign-in-with-linkedin-button-to-your-android-app-using-kotlin/ This one is actually good. But the problem is that it is in Kotlin, whereas I use java.

Comment: Please try to find the tutorial for java.if you got no luck then do let me know we will write this kotlin code in java it's not a big deal.